# Performance of copying a file with fread/fwrite to USB

Tags: c++, c

I'm in front of a piece of code, which copies a file to a usb-device.
Following part is the important one:

```
while((bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, 16*1024, m_hSource)) && !bAbort) {
    // write to target
    long bytesWritten = fwrite(buf, 1, bytesRead, m_hTarget);

    m_lBytesCopied += bytesWritten;
```

The thing, the customer said, it's pretty slow in comparison to normal pc<->usb speed. I didn't code this, so it's my job, to optimize.

So I was wondering, if it's a better approach to first read the complete file and then write the file in one step. But I don't know how error-prone this would be.
The code also check after each copystep if all bytes where written correctly, so that might also slow down the process.

I'm not that c++ & hardware guru, so I'm asking you guys, how I could speed things up and keep the copying successful.

Comment: Look elsewhere for the bottleneck.  You may get a small improvement changing the buffer size, but your problem is probably something else.

Comment: Well, that's the only part that is doing something with this particular problem. So it can be only the code.

Comment: Remove the check that the bytes were written correctly.  If you cannot trust the first write, then you cannot trust the following read you use for verification.  (I assume you are checking bytesWritten for errors.)

Comment: The posted code looks fine when it comes to performance. Is there anything in the part of the code you didn't post that may be causing a problem?

Comment: Rather than reading back the data to verify it, use fsync().

Comment: I have heard that sometimes it may help to switch the size and count parameters. Try using `fwrite(buf, bytesRead, 1, m_hTarget)` and see if it helps. Note that this won't work for fread since if you specify size being 1000, and there less than 1000 bytes left to read, the function will fail.

Comment: So, perhaps the device is recognized as a USB 1.1 device. USB 1 is dead slow..

Comment: Go for copying file using memory mapped I/O...just a suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to **read/write in big chunk**. 16M, 32M are not bad for copying file.
2. If you **just** want to copy the file you can always **invoke `system()`** It'll be faster.
3. > The code also check after each copystep if all bytes where written correctly, so that might also slow down the process.

   You can check it by creating **hash** of bigger chunk. Like splitting the file into 64M chunks. Then match hashes of those chunks. Bittorrent protocol has this feature.
4. If you have **`mmap` or `MapViewOfFile` available, map the file first**. Then write it to usb. This way **read operation will be handled by kernel**.
5. Kerrek just commented about using `memcpy` on `mmap`. **`memcpy` with 2 `mmap`ed file** seems great.

Also note that, Most recent operating systems writes to USB stick when they are being removed. Before removal  it just writes the data in a cache. So copy from OS may appear faster.

Comment: @KerrekSB +1. `memcpy` with 2 `mmap`ed file seems a great option. Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

What about overlapping reads and writes?

In the current code, the total time is `time(read original) + time(write copy)`, if you read the first block, then while writing it start reading the second block, etc. your total time would be `max(time(read original), time(write copy))` (plus the time reading/writing the first and last blocks that won't be pipelined).

It could be almost half the time if reading and writing takes more or less the same time.

You can do it with two threads or with asynchronous IO. Unfortunately, threads and async IO are platform dependent, so you'll have to check your system manual or choose appropriate portable libraries.

Comment: AFAIK, USB I/O is also mostly platform dependent, is it not?

Comment: @AndréCaron I guess yes if you are building a driver, but in this case I think it is just accessing the filesystem, so you can `fopen` files (and that is standard).

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with some OS specific functions that for sure do this faster that anything written only with c/c++ functions.

For Linux this could be [sendfile](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) function. For Windows [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28VS.85%29.aspx) will do the job.